# printing lines between start and end point

Tags: python

Let's say I have a text file in this format:

```
***a
foo bar
lorem ipsum
dolor
---a
```

I want to print the lines between `***a` and `---a` I'm trying to do it with this:

```
def printlines():
    pattern = open('text.txt').read().splitlines()
    for line in pattern:
        if line == "***a":
            pass
            while line != "---a":
                print line

        else:
            pass
```

But it prints `***a` in an infinite loop. How can I solve this?

Comment: how many times can it appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple occurrences you can start an inner loop when you hit the start line, which is equivalent to what your while is trying to do:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip() == "***a":
            print("")
            for line in f:
                if line.rstrip() == "---a":
                    break
                print(line.rstrip())
```

Which for:

```
***a
foo bar
lorem ipsum
dolor
---a
***a
bar bar
foobar
foob
---a
```

Would output:

```
foo bar
lorem ipsum
dolor

bar bar
foobar
foob
```

If you want to have lines without the newlines we can `map` them off and still iterate line by line:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    # itertools.imap python2
    f = map(str.rstrip, f)
    for line in f:
        if line == "***a":
            print("")
            for line in f:
                if line == "---a":
                    break
                print(line)
```

Comment: Hey @Padraic  why can't we simply put `if line !='****a' or line!='-----a'` and put the rest lines in a `list`

Comment: @NikhilParmar, because `"foo" != "foo\n"`,  because we are not splitting the lines we still keep the newline characters

Comment: I added a way to remove them without the need to call rstrip in the code repeatedly

Answer (score 3):

Use a state machine. That means, once you see your opening pattern, set a state so you know that the following lines are now relevant to you. Then keep looking out for the ending pattern to turn it off:

```
def printlines():
    # this is our state
    isWithin = False

    with open('text.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            # Since the line contains the line breaking character,
            # we have to remove that first
            line = line.rstrip()

            # check for the patterns to change the state
            if line == "***a":
                isWithin = True
            elif line == "---a":
                isWithin = False

            # check whether we’re within our state
            elif isWithin:
                print line
```

Since we only print once we’re in the `isWithin` state, we can easily skip any part out side of the `***a`/`---a` pattern. So processing the following file would correctly print out `Hello` and `World` and nothing else:

```
Foo
***a
Hello
---a
Bar
***a
World
---a
Baz
```

Also, you should use the `with` statement to open your file, and iterate over the file object directly instead of reading it and calling `splitlines()`. That way you make sure that the file is properly closed, and you only ever read one line after another, making this more memory efficient.

Comment: line will never be equal to if `"***a"`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for the (not really obvious) reminder ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use [break](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) and [continue](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
def printlines():
    pattern = open('text.txt').read().splitlines()
    for line in pattern:
        if line == "***a":
           continue
        if line == "---a":
           break
        print line
```

**Break**

> The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the smallest enclosing
>   for or while loop.

**Continue**

> The continue statement, also borrowed from C, continues with the next
>   iteration of the loop.

Comment: This will also print lines outside of the `***a` / `---a` pattern though.

Comment: True, it's only valid for the given example as a way to illustrate `break` and `continue` statements.